# How to change color of line chart in achartengine for Android dynamically?

Tags: android, achartengine, linechart

I am using Achartengine for LineChart. I already added line color for XYSeriesRenderer object. I am getting dynamic values from a library to draw chart. If x value reached maximum, I need to change the color of line chart. I am using only one series. I tried and I couldn't. Is there any way to change line color dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Declaring and instantiating objects:
XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mTimeRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
XYSeriesRenderer mCurrentRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();

// Defining XYRenderer properties
mCurrentRenderer.setColor(Color.CYAN);
// Associating XYRenderer to the XYMultipleSeriesRenderer
mTimeRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(mCurrentRenderer);
```

---

```
//{...}
// You could get your XYRenderer later on with:
mCurrentRenderer = mTimeRenderer.getSeriesRendererAt(0);
```

Of course, you could repaint dynamically your chart and change your renderer properties at any time.

**Explanation:**

`XYSeriesRenderer` objects are used as `XYRenderer` containers.

The way you set your line color is using the `XYRenderer.setColor(int color)` method.

You might get your current renderer calling `getSeriesRendererAt(int index)` over your `XYSeriesRenderer` or you might already have a `XYRenderer` object to interact with.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the color this way:

```
renderer.setColor(newColor);
```

And then repaint the chart:

```
chartView.repaint();
```